# Issue in api containing "/." in POST API

Tags: api, post, retrofit2

I need to hit an api with the url
https://api.abc.com/customers/customers/:1/points.
The above url gives the response in postman. But gives 404 when implemented in code.
Header includes authorization token, Content-Type, Accept. Here's the code

```
 override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
    val token = PreferenceHandler.readString(NavigationApplication.getContext(), "bearertoken", 
"")

    val builder = chain.request().newBuilder()
    if (token != null && token != (""))
        Log.e("accesstoken", token)
    builder.addHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.abc.com; version=2")
    builder.addHeader("Content-type","application/json")
    builder.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)

    return chain.proceed(builder.build())

}
```

and body is in json format as:

```
     val paramObject = JSONObject()
     val imagesArray = JSONArray()
     val innerobj = JSONObject()
  innerobj.put("external_id","gkt567k8-f357-45af-877e-99267093ax99")
  // innerobj.put("lat", location?.latitude!!)
  innerobj.put("lat", 30.7046)
  innerobj.put("lon", 76.7179)
  //innerobj.put("lon", location?.longitude!!)
    innerobj.put("alt", 12.3)
    innerobj.put("course", 330.10)
    innerobj.put("speed", 15.64)
    imagesArray.put(innerobj)
    paramObject.put("points", imagesArray)
```

and here's the api

```
  @POST("customers/customers/1/points")
  fun getUser(@Body body: String): Call<ResponsePojo>
```

I'm not getting the response instead 404 error code

Comment: The URL you tested with Postman contains `/:1` (colon after the slash) whereas in your Retrofit API interface the URL doesn't have colon before the customer ID (1). That's why you're getting a 404 error. I don't why do you need a colon in between slashes.

Comment: The /:1 was written in the documentation of the concerned services. I have resolved it by removing the colon and replaced  "1" with actual  value required in the url.